# How to Align left the menu bar items pure JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

i hope to  use a navigation menu bar which extracted from another post in stack overflow. here is my code

CSS

```
<style>
 header, nav {
  background-color:#06C;font-family:'Open Sans';
}

header {
  width:100%;display:flex;align-items:center;
  height:80px;color:#FFF;justify-content:flex-start;
} /* we use flex display to position the hamburger icon on the side of the AndroiCSS h2 element */

#hamburger {
  cursor:pointer;
} /* add the small hand cursor pointer to indicate this element is clickable; it triggers the jQuery on click */

header * {
  margin:0 15px;
}

.fa-bars, header h2 {
  font-size:28px!important;
}

header h2 {
  font-weight:400!important;
}

nav {
  display:flex;flex-direction:column;width:0;align-items:center;
  transition:width 0.2s ease;

}

nav.open {
width:250px;
height:100%;
  }

nav.close {
  width:0;
}


nav * {
  color:#FFF!important;font-family:'Open Sans';font-size:20px!important;margin-right:15px;
}

nav a {
   text-decoration:none!important;
  border-top:0.5px solid gray;width:100%;text-align:center;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;height:55px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
} /* this changes the bg color on hover over the nav element */

 </style>
```

HTML

```
<header>
    <i id="hamburger" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    <h2>AndroidCSS</h2>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i>  <span>Terms and conditions</span></a> <!-- nav menu no need for <ul> or <li> tags here -->
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i><span>Privacy Policy</span></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span>About Us</span></a>
    <a href="#)"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>Help</span></a>
  </nav>
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
<script>
   $("#hamburger").click(function(){
    $("nav").toggleClass('open', 'close');
});

$("a").click(function(){
    $("nav").toggleClass('open', 'close');
});
    </script>
```

1. I want to get  align left menu items with left padding 10px.(tried lot of ways. but unsuccessful)
2. I want to put hamburger icon in right side of navigation bar.
3. I need to close opened menu on  outside clicking using pure javaScript.(by clicking anywhere outside)
   all must be responsive.

please help me to solve these three problems. it's highly appreciated.

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/akslk/105phkog/10/

Comment: Please create a pluker/fiddle so that we can get more idea.

Comment: there is somthing error in your code

Comment: if you can update your question with codepen https://codepen.io/pen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove the `display: flex` from the `<a>` tags;
- Add a `display: flex !important`, `flex-direction: column` and
  `justify-content: flex-start` to your `<nav>` tag;

Here's an example:

[jsfiddle.net/mdyvzx09/2](http://jsfiddle.net/mdyvzx09/2)

Feedback: adding linebreaks in your CSS code can improve its readability :)

Comment: No 1 problem solved. No 2 and 3 problems still not solved. help me!

Comment: But navigation menu not fully closed. few pixels remaining opened. please mouse hover and then you can see it on left edge. how to sole it?

Comment: Thanks a lot ,Celso Wellington. everything is fine. wonderful coding. really appreciated. but only one thing must be corrected. Navi panel height must be 100%. Thanks.

Comment: I've solved your main problem. Check out the edited jsfiddle in the original comment and you'll see a better version of the answer.
Now, if you want to push demands like this, you might want to hire a developer to do the job for you. Stack overflow is made to aid your researches, not to develop the product for you.